# cypress cache clear hanging

Tags: node.js, cypress

For context I am working in windows 10 with Node.js.

Having set up cypress successfully after a load of trial and error in one project file I am starting from scratch with another project file to work out the exact steps.

For some reason it is failing with the new attempt and having noticed the errors show v 7/3/0 whereas the errors for the previous showed v 7.2.0 I thought I'd return to the first project file and try

`cypress clear cache` as recommended at [docs.cypress.io/guides/references/troubleshooting](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/troubleshooting#Isolate-the-Problem) which I've assumed that was to be run at the Node.js command prompt.

Having done so Node.js is just hanging.

Is this expected behaviour?

Have I misunderstood the instructions?

Thanks

Comment: You can do that manually by `npx cypress cache path` and going to delete the content there. Also my developer colleagues said that we need to delete the node Modules folder in the project and cypress, update to Nodejs 14 and install and rebuild everything from scratch for the migration. May be this is a part of the problem